Real number set in roster form.
I have read in a textbook that the set of real numbers , $\mathbb R$ , can not be represented in tabular or roster from.
(Tabular or Roster representation is when elements of the sets are put in curly braces {}, separated by commas.}
My question is ,if the following represents  $\mathbb R$ $?$
$$\{-\infty,...,0-1/\infty,0,0+1/\infty,...,\infty\}$$

$ \mathbb Z $ in tabular form is  $$ {-\infty,...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...,\infty} $$

No, the expression does not fit because with $\mathbb R4cwe cannot formulate a rule that can fill the dots.

Firstly... $\infty$ is not a number.  Secondly, $\frac{1}{\infty}$ is not a number.  Third, the "number after $0$" doesn't exist... for any number $\epsilon>0$ you have a number $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which is smaller.

It is quite useless, like writing $\mathbb R = { \text { all the real numbers} }$

To be clear... if I were to try to write the natural numbers... I could do so as ${1,2,3,4,\dots}$ and it is clear that this can continue with the next number as $5$ and then $6$ after that etc... that if I had decided to write the first $n$ numbers I have a clear and unambiguous way such that I can write the $n+1$'st number in such a way that I can guarantee that every natural number is eventually written.  I could do this also with the integers as ${0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\dots}$ and it is clear the next number will be $5$ then $-5$ and so on... if I write $n$ numbers I know the next...

Even with the positive rational numbers, I could do it in a roundabout way... ${1,2,\frac{1}{2},3,\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},4,\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4},5,\dots}$ and still guarantee I'll eventually have written everything.  There is no way to do this for the reals.  There are several proofs of this that it is impossible, most famous among them being Cantor's Diagonalization argument.  Your attempt fails because these $\frac{1}{\infty}$ objects don't exist and even if they did no amount of adding them together will have you go from one real number to a "next real number", much less from 0 to 1.
